# What audio codecs are supported by Windows Phone's A2DP feature?

Tags: bluetooth

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) A2DP enabled devices need to support the SBC codec only for audio transmission. MP3, AAC, ... can be supported but are not required to.

Which audio codecs are supported by Windows Phone 7's A2DP feature?

Comment: Not an answer, but I have used mp3, aac, and whatever format the marketplace serves.

Comment: @Joe: This is about what codec is used to transmit raw audio over Bluetooth, not about the format you are playing. Usually it is like: MP3 on Phone --> Raw --> SBC over BT --> Raw --> Ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [official Windows Phone Support on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/WinPhoneSupport/status/203534957107355648) all support audio on the phone **should** be supported over bluetooth.

[Supported Media Codecs for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28VS.92%29.aspx)

This answer your question?

Comment: Thank you! I think this answers my question. Though there is still a "should" in it. ;-) But never mind, thank you!

Comment: Yes, "should" is a problematic thing in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the knowledgebase for [`kbwp7 ad2p`](http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=kbwp7+ad2p) only yields one result which isn't really promising, so there is no information released about this. Since a lot only implement SBC, it's fair to assume Windows Phone didn't implement more than SBC either, simply because it doesn't need to implement it because it would be compatible with most mobile stuff using SBC.

Comment: So I guess the correct answer is: "There is no answer." ? ;-)